# Are XAML UI designers common today?

Tags: design, gui

I am thinking about creating a silverlight application, and I lack the skills to create a good looking UI.
Today's graphic designers usually know HTML and CSS and thus save me the trouble of doing something I am not very good with.
Is this the same case with XAML?
Do I have to hire two employees for this job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight is a pretty cool technology, but I'm seriously concerned about its [future](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834). However, if you want a cool UI done in XAML... you have several options.

1. Hire a Silverlight/WPF dev and hope they also design / See #3
2. Hire a UX designer with XAML skillz
3. Hire a great graphic designer and then hire #1 OR you can use the built-in Ai/PSD to XAML tools in Expression Studio (design).

Tons of options, if you are a small company you may even qualify for Bizspark ( a free version of Expression Studio).

Good luck.